# OpenCV java Mat CvType 'Mat data type is not compatible'

Tags: java, opencv

I have an image created with `new Mat(width, height,CvType.CV_8UC4);` for which i want to set a pixel to a certain value. But i am getting `Mat data type is not compatible: 24`

I added some intermediate steps in the method for easier debugging.

```java
   public Mat matrix;

   public void setARGB(int x, int y, int argb) {
        Color color = new Color(argb, true);
        int[] channels = getColorArray(color);
        int matrixType = matrix.type();
        int depth = CvType.depth(matrixType);
 
        matrix.put(x, y, channels);
    }
```

When debugging i have

```
channels = [255, 176, 192, 50]
matrixType = 24
depth = 0
```

That `depth` confuses me, i had expected 4 for this ?

When i look at the code for this put method in OpenCV 4.7.0 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv/4.7.0-0 )

```java
    // javadoc:Mat::put(row,col,data)
    public int put(int row, int col, int[] data) {
        int t = type();
        if (data == null || data.length % CvType.channels(t) != 0)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Provided data element number (" +
                            (data == null ? 0 : data.length) +
                            ") should be multiple of the Mat channels count (" +
                            CvType.channels(t) + ")");
        if (CvType.depth(t) == CvType.CV_32S) {
            return nPutI(nativeObj, row, col, data.length, data);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Mat data type is not compatible: " + t);
    }
```

`(CvType.depth(t) == CvType.CV_32S)` this results in 0 not being equal to 4 and  throwing that Exception in the last line.

I am not really sure what is wrong and how i am supposed the color of a pixel.

Thanks for your feedback !